# chart resizing in ng2-google-charts

Tags: charts, angular5, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have created a chart using this documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-charts.

`<google-chart style="height: 100%!important; width: 80%!important;" [data]="pieChartData"></google-chart>`

It appears very small for a big screen. Is there anyway I can resize it for a big screen?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just specify values for width and height in options. But it is not responsive.

```
pieChartData =  {
  chartType: 'PieChart',
  dataTable: [
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ],
  options: {'title': 'Tasks', 
            'width': 700,
            'height': 600},
};
```

Comment: In order to make it responsive use css like
`overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;`